# Seeing that the category of Simplicial sets is Cartesian closed

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Consider the category $\textbf{S.Sets}$. I want to understand why this category is cartesian closed and why we defoni the exponential object the way we do. That is consider $3$ Simplicial sets $X,Y,Z$, that is contravariant functors. Define $\text{map}_{[n]}(Y,Z):=Hom_{\textbf{S.Sets}}(\triangle[n]\times Y,Z)$. Then it's claimed that

$Hom_{\textbf{S.Sets}}(X\times Y,Z)=Hom_{\textbf{S.Sets}}(X,\text{map}(Y,Z))$

I have tried to see why this is true by using the definition of natural transformation but so far I have not gotten anywhere satisfying, that is I don't understand why we need to do the product with the simplical set $\triangle[n]$ in order to get the desired result.

Any enlightment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a proof, but maybe you can convince yourself that is the only thing it can be by setting $X = \Delta^n$ and using the Yoneda lemma.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the Yoneda lemma. Given two simplifical sets, we can compute the exponential object $Y^X$: given a finite ordinal $n$, the Yoneda lemma says that $Y^X n\simeq \mathtt{sSet}(\Delta [n], Y^X)$. By the defining adjunction, it means that $Y^X n\simeq \mathtt{sSet}(\Delta [n]\times X, Y)$.
Hope that helps!